# I can not see my CreateJS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple game in CREATEJS. It's about being able to move the Superman, kill him by clicking on the kryptonite and a couple of other things.
The problem comes when I open the web and the only thing I see is a blank box.
I leave the CreateJS and html code.

I need to see if someone is able to enlighten me. I read that it is possible that it is necessary to make a preload or something like that. I do not know, seriously.

```html
var stage;

var startDrag = function(event) 
{
// Esta función sirve para que al arrastrar no se haga desde el punto central del grupo, 
// sino desde aquel punto donde se hizo click
var grupo = event.currentTarget;
var offset = grupo.globalToLocal(event.stageX, event.stageY);

// Se evitaran problemas si el grupo estuviera escalado
grupo.offsetX = offset.x * grupo.scaleX; 
grupo.offsetY = offset.y * grupo.scaleY;
}

var drag = function(event)
{
var grupo = event.currentTarget;

// La nueva posicion se calcula como las coordenadas en pantalla donde se hizo click menos
// el desfase (dentro del grupo) calculado en la funcion startDrag
grupo.x = event.stageX - grupo.offsetX;
grupo.y = event.stageY - grupo.offsetY;
stage.update();
}

var stopDrag = function(event)
{
var grupo = event.currentTarget;

grupo.x = event.stageX - grupo.offsetX;
grupo.y = event.stageY - grupo.offsetY;
stage.update();
}

var kill = function(event){

stage.removeChildAt(1);
stage.update();
}

var borrar = function(event)
{
var objeto = event.currentTarget;
stage.removeChild(heli);
stage.update();
}

function inicializar() 
{
var grupo;

stage = new createjs.Stage('escenario
grupo = new createjs.Container();
grupo.x = stage.canvas.width/2;
grupo.y = stage.canvas.height/2;

grupo.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag); // Escucha la pulsación del botón del ratón
grupo.addEventListener('pressmove', drag); // Escucha movimiento del ratón, después de haber sido pulsado
grupo.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag); // Escucha la liberación del botón del ratón

fondo = new Image();
fondo.src = "images/ciudad.jpg";

imagen = new Image();
imagen.src = "images/sp.png";

imagen2 = new Image();
imagen2.src = "images/kriptonita.png";

imagenheli = new Image();
imagenheli.src = "images/helicoptero.png";

fondo.onload = function() {
fondo = new createjs.Bitmap(fondo);
stage.addChild(fondo);


bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(imagen);
grupo.addChild(bitmap);
grupo.offsetX = 0;
grupo.offsetY = 0;
stage.addChild(grupo);


bitmap2 = new createjs.Bitmap(imagen2);
stage.addChild(bitmap2);
bitmap2.addEventListener('click', kill);


heli = new createjs.Bitmap(imagenheli);
heli.x = 300;
heli.y=20;
stage.addChild(heli);
heli.addEventListener('click', borrar);

stage.update();
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>XXI Salón Internacional del Cómic de Jaén</title>
    <link href="css/rejilla960fluido.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/miestilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="libs/videoplayer.js" type="application/x-javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/createjs-2013.12.12.min.js" type="application/x-javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/create.js" type="application/x-javascript"></script>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300i" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body onload="inicializar();">
            <div id="social" class="container_12">
          <ul class="grid_6 push_5">
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="ifacebook"></a><br>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="itwitter"></a><br>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com" id="ituenti"></a><br>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><br>
    <br class="clear">

<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_1">
    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; margin-left: -2px" src="images/goku.png">
  </div>

    <center><canvas class="fondo grid_10" id="canvas" width="100%" height="auto"></canvas></center>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = function(){
      canvas.width = img.naturalWidth
      canvas.height = img.naturalHeight
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      }
      img.src = 'images/logoprueba.png';
    </script>

      <div class="grid_1">
    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; margin-left: -22px;" src="images/vegeta.png">
  </div>
</div><br class="clear">

    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="programacion.html">Programación</a></li>
        <li><a href="comics.html">Cómics</a></li>
        <li><a href="autores.html">Autores</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="sub"><a href="autor1.html">Laura Falconi</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="autor2.html">Quino</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="autor3.html">Dante Quintero</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="autor4.html">Ivanka Trump</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="autor5.html">Paco Roca</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="autor6.html">Rafa Fonteriz</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="galeria.html">Galería</a></li>
        <li><a href="estadisticas.html">Estadísticas</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="juegos.html">Juegos</a>        
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="sub"><a href="test.html">Cuestionario</a></li>
            <li class="sub"><a href="juego.html">Pregunta Estrella</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="jaen.html">Jaén</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a class="sub2" href="monumentos.html">Monumentos</a></li>
            <li><a class="sub2" href="gastronomia.html">Gastronomía</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="localizacion.html">Localización</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  <h1>Salva a la ciudad</h1>

      <canvas id="escenario"  class="fondo" width="500" height="400">Este navegador no soporta Canvas</canvas>
       
       <center><p class="cita fondo "> Intruscciones: <br>
        Puedes mover a Superman. <br>
        Puedes destruir a Superman haciendo click en la Kryptonita. <br>
        Puedes destruir el helicoptero haciendo click en el.<br>
        Puedes destruir la Kryptonita haciendo click en ella, después de haber destruido a Superman. </p></center>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either the 'defer' or 'async' attribute inside the 'script' tag, see: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html for more information.

An example of use:

```
<script src="/path/to/your/script.js"></script>

<!-- Run after the HTML is parsed -->
<script src="/run/after/html/parse.js" defer></script>

<!-- Run once the file has been imported -->
<script src="/run/on/download.js" async></script>
```

It is very useful to not that the 'defered' scripts will run in the order they were imported.

For example:

```
<!-- This will also block html parsing -->
<script src="/this/will/run/first.js"></script>

<!-- Run after the HTML is parsed -->
<script src="/this/will/run/second.js" defer></script>
<script src="/this/will/run/third.js" defer></script>
<script src="/this/will/run/fourth.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with this solution. I don't see anything when I open the .hmtl. Only a white square.

Comment: Try replacing: 'document.getElementById('canvas')' with 'document.querySelectory('canvas')'

Comment: My real problem is here. <body onload="inicializar();"> and here  <canvas id="escenario"  class="fondo" width="500" height="400">Este navegador no soporta Canvas</canvas>
       
       <center><p class="cita fondo "> Intruscciones: <br>
        Puedes mover a Superman. <br>
        Puedes destruir a Superman haciendo click en la Kryptonita. <br>
        Puedes destruir el helicoptero haciendo click en el.<br>
        Puedes destruir la Kryptonita haciendo click en ella, después de haber destruido a Superman. </p></center>
  
 </body>

Comment: `stage = new createjs.Stage('escenario` needs to be `stage = new createjs.Stage('escenario');` maybe your js is just not executing?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are only updating your stage one time (when the first image loads), and then when interactions happen. Typically games have a stage update every "tick". You should at least ensure all your images are loaded before updating. Add this to your init function to see if it helps:

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
```

Additionally, check your console. As @scagood pointed out, there should be a run-time error as your code has some errors.